# Async function calls not executing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I'm trying to copy large set of files from one S3 to another S3, using asynchronous method. To achieve the same, the large set of files is broken into batches and each batch is handed over to a list of async method. The issue is, each async method is not processing more than 1 file in the batch, whereas each batch contains more than 1k files, not sure why async doesn't go back to process the remaining files.

Here is the code:

```cs
public void CreateAndExecuteSpawn(string srcBucket, List<List<string>> pdfFileList, IAmazonS3 s3client)
{
    int i = 0;
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    LambdaLogger.Log("PDF Set count: " + pdfFileList.Count.ToString());
    foreach (var list in pdfFileList)
        actions.Add(() => RenameFilesAsync(srcBucket, list, s3client));

    foreach (var method in actions)
    {
        method.Invoke();
        LambdaLogger.Log("Mehtod invoked: "+ i++.ToString());
    }
}
            
public async void RenameFilesAsync(string srcBucket, List<string> pdfFiles, IAmazonS3 s3client)
{
    LambdaLogger.Log("In RenameFileAsync method");
    CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
    {
        SourceBucket = srcBucket,
        DestinationBucket = srcBucket
    };
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in pdfFiles)
        {
            if (!file.Contains("index.xml"))
            {
                string[] newFilename = file.Split('{');
                string[] destKey = file.Split('/');
                copyRequest.SourceKey = file;
                copyRequest.DestinationKey = destKey[0] + "/" + destKey[1] + "/Renamed/" + newFilename[1];
                LambdaLogger.Log("About to rename File: " + file);
                //Here after copying one file, function doesn't return to foreach loop
                CopyObjectResponse response = await s3client.CopyObjectAsync(copyRequest);
                //await s3client.CopyObjectAsync(copyRequest);
                LambdaLogger.Log("Rename done: ");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log(ex.Message);
        LambdaLogger.Log(copyRequest.DestinationKey);
    }
}
        
public void FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
{
    //Some code here
    CreateAndExecuteSpawn(bucket, pdfFileSet, s3client);
}
```

Comment: [Avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void)

Comment: You have a bug. You never *await* the asynchronous operations, so you have no way of knowing if they run at all. Don't use `async void`. Use `async Task` and make sure you `await` the returned task

Comment: If you want to execute all renames in parallel you can replace `CreateAndExecuteSpawn` with `var renames=files.Select(f=> RenameFilesAsync(bucket,file,client)); await Task.WhenAll(renames);`. If you want to execute them sequentially, you only need a simple `foreach` that calls `await RenameFilesAsync(...);`

Comment: Do you mean public async Task RenameFilesAsync(string srcBucket, List<string> pdfFiles, IAmazonS3 s3client)

Comment: Yes, I want to execute all renames in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fix the batch so that it will process the batches one at a time. [Avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void); use `async Task` instead:

```
public async Task CreateAndExecuteSpawnAsync(string srcBucket, List<List<string>> pdfFileList, IAmazonS3 s3client)
{
    int i = 0;
    List<Func<Task>> actions = new();
    LambdaLogger.Log("PDF Set count: " + pdfFileList.Count.ToString());
    foreach (var list in pdfFileList)
        actions.Add(() => RenameFilesAsync(srcBucket, list, s3client));

    foreach (var method in actions)
    {
        await method();
        LambdaLogger.Log("Mehtod invoked: "+ i++.ToString());
    }
}
            
public async Task RenameFilesAsync(string srcBucket, List<string> pdfFiles, IAmazonS3 s3client)
```

Then you can add asynchronous concurrency within each batch. The current code is just a `foreach` loop, so of course it only processes one at a time. You can change this to be asynchronously concurrent by `Select`ing the tasks to run and then doing a `Task.WhenAll` at the end:

```
LambdaLogger.Log("In RenameFileAsync method");
CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket = srcBucket,
    DestinationBucket = srcBucket
};
try
{
  var tasks = pdfFiles
      .Where(file => !file.Contains("index.xml"))
      .Select(async file =>
      {
         string[] newFilename = file.Split('{');
         string[] destKey = file.Split('/');
         copyRequest.SourceKey = file;
         copyRequest.DestinationKey = destKey[0] + "/" + destKey[1] + "/Renamed/" + newFilename[1];
         LambdaLogger.Log("About to rename File: " + file);
         CopyObjectResponse response = await s3client.CopyObjectAsync(copyRequest);
         LambdaLogger.Log("Rename done: ");
      })
      .ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Marvelous!!, Could I kindly request an explanation as what was going wrong with my code?

Comment: @Aniruddha: It was a `foreach` loop, which only processes items one at a time.